# How to convert a lead to a specific Account recordTypes based on condition on Lead using LeadConvert database method

Tags: apex, account, record-type, leads, lead-conversion

I have a Field called "Business Type" on LEAD which is of type picklist. I am using LeadConvert method to convert a lead to Account, contact, Opportunity. While I convert the lead, I want to assign the recordtype of the account dynamically with respect to **"Business Type"**. How is this possible when using LeadConvert Class. At present, a default recordtype of account is getting assigned when a lead is converted.

Documentation for LeadConvert class: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_dml_convertLead.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to DavidCheng suggestion,

If you map the value of `Lead.BusinessType` to a field in Account, say `Account.Business_Type__c` (via Lead Mapping), then you can either use

- Before Save Flow to coerce the `Account.RecordtypeId`
- Before Insert Trigger to coerce the `Account.RecordtypeId`

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to specify an Account record type during lead conversion.  Either you'll have to create the account before the lead conversion and use `setAccountId()`, or change the new account's record type after lead conversion using on the `ConvertedAccountId` field.